# How to install marvel plugin in elasticsearch 7.3.1?

Tags: elasticsearch, plugins, search-engine, elasticsearch-marvel

[image: output on trying to install]I am not able to install marvel plugin in elasticsearch. I am following the book "Elasticsearch:The Definitive Guide" and I am stucked in installing marvel plugin. In the book the cmd was

```
./bin/plugin -i elasticsearch/marvel/latest
```

And I change to the below as this doesn't works anyway.

None of the following commands are working. It says unknown plugin marvel-agent or unknown plugin license and also same for marvel.

```
>>sudo bin/elasticsearch-plugin install license

>>sudo bin/elasticsearch-plugin install marvel-agent

>>sudo bin/elasticsearch-plugin install marvel
```

I tried installing different plugin analysis-icu, and it worked. But didn't worked with marvel

Comment: Can you share us console output exactly?..when you try install

Comment: Added the screenshot @GiovaniSalazar , it shows "ERROR: Unknown plugin marvel"

Comment: @supernatural Did you find a solution? from the book, I should view Marvel at localhost:9200/_plugin/marvel How do I view it now?

Comment: Ok. I found the answer: so Kibana is a UI tool, which will include Marvel and Sense in the book. After install/run Kibana, this is the url to use the console localhost:5601/app/dev_tools#/console

Answer (score 5):

From version 5.0 onward, Marvel is part of X-Pack. For more information, see Monitoring the Elastic Stack.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/marvel/current/release-notes.html

Comment: ... and for newer versions of Elasticsearch X-Pack is included by default.

Comment: What does this mean? from the book, I should view Marvel at http://localhost:9200/_plugin/marvel/ 

How do I view it now?

Comment: Ok. I found the answer: so Kibana is a UI tool, which will include Marvel and Sense in the book. After install/run Kibana, this is the url to use the console http://localhost:5601/app/dev_tools#/console